# Observable - start to emit conditionally

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

Is there a way to start emitting values conditionally from an observable? In my case, subscribers of the `.asObservable()` function should only get a first value AFTER `CurrentUser` has been initialized.

```
export class CurrentUser {

    private currentUser$: Observable<CurrentUser>;
    private currentUserBehaviorSubject: BehaviorSubject<CurrentUser>;

    public name: string = "";

    constructor() {
        this.currentUserBehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject(this);
        this.currentUser$ = this.currentUserBehaviorSubject.asObservable();
    }

    public asObservable(): Observable<CurrentUser> {
        // 
        if(user.name.length > 0){
            return this.currentUser$;
        }
        else {
            // ?????
        }
    }

    public initialize(string name){
        this.name = name;
        this.currentUserBehaviorSubject.next(this);
    }
}

export class SampleComponent {
    constructor(
        currentUser: CurrentUser
    ) {
        currentUser.asObservable().subscribe(
            (u: CurrentUser) => {
                // i only want an INITIALIZED user here
            },
            error => {},
            () => { }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Who initialize the sample component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you could in your `asObservable()` method always return an Observable and just suppress emissions using the `skipUntil()` operator until `currentUserBehaviorSubject` emits (I guess that's how you know CurrentUser has been initialized):

```
public asObservable(): Observable<CurrentUser> {
    return this.currentUser$
        .skipUntil(this.currentUserBehaviorSubject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How I see that :

```
export class CurrentUser {
    subject: Subject<CurrentUser> = new Subject<CurrentUser>();
    observable: Observable<CurrentUser = this.subject.asObservable();

    constructor() {
        // Do your business
        this.subject.next(this);
    }
}
```

And in your components, just subscribe to the `observable` property.

This way, when you initialize a new CurrentUser, your observers are notified. Is it what you want, or did I misunderstood ?

Answer (score 0):

I usually manages such cases in following way:

```
  private someDataSource = new BehaviorSubject<someData>(null);
  private initSubj$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

getData(): Observable<someData> {
  return this.someDataSource.pipe(
    skipUntill(this.initSubj$.pipe(filter(d => d === true)))
  )
}

setData(data) {
  this.initSubj$.next(true);
  this.someDataSource.next(d);

}
```

thanks to this, management of init/noninit data dpeneds only on setting data to your source observable, that is chained to initi observable. This can be further optimized to use static observable as the initialization one, but the end result is:

You don't need any if/else in your emission logic, consumers that will subscribe to data prior initialization will be just queued and have to wait until first partition of data will arrive.